# Turning an old router in to a swich

Tags: networking, router, switch

I'm playing with the idea of turning an old router which lying around in to a switch and attaching this to my current router. It's not so much because I need the extra ports, mainly because I am quite new to networking and want to have a play around.

I've seen a few tutorials on the internet which seem pretty straight forward - basically disable DHCP and you're practically good to go.

My main question is, how do the IPs get assigned to the devices attached to the switch if the switch has no DHCP facility? How does the router 'know where these devices are?'

When you connect the switch to the router, does the switch make note of this being the Default Gateway and also store the port this gateway is attached to? Do the connected devices then automatically pass straight through the switch to the router to get their IPs assigned? Then any data that needs to go to these extra devices, does this just get passed to the switch and that does a NAT like procedure passing on to MAC addresses?

I know this is probably very basic, but once I've got my head around this bit of detail it will help me a great deal when I come to setting this up.

Thanks in advance and all the best.

Answer (score 0):

Without knowing the make/model of the router, I can only assume turning off DHCP in this case will allow it to be a dummy switch, in which case anything you connect to it will get their IP addresses via the router your switch is now connected to.

The switch should then be invisible to the network, with devices connected to them simply acting like they are connected back to the router, and thus the rest of the network.
The caveat being that the connected devices will share that single link back to your router, and thus your WAN (internet) and anything else connected directly to your router. In most cases this isn't an issue if you're using gigabit ports and plan your bandwidth usage accordingly.

Answer (score 0):

Switches work at layer 2 in the OSI model, with MAC addresses - they have no concept of IP addresses (you do have layer 3 switches/routers, but that's not your question). DHCP works on a broadcast basis, and a switch will forward these packets to all ports/machines. You only need (and should only have!) one DHCP server on any given subnet.

In your case of repurposing a router, connect everything to the LAN ports, not the WAN port.

Comment: Tanks for the detailed reply. This is the main thing that is confusing me, obviously you couldn't have 4 devices plugged in to one port of a router, but in essence this is what a switch is doing. Say for example my switch is plugged in to port 4 of the router, with 4 devices attached to it. Data comes in to the router from the internet with the destination of device 2 on the switch. How does the data reach the correct destination? Normally I would assume the router would know which IP address is on which port and just forward it accordingly, but in this case there will be 4 IPs on one port?

Comment: Switches keep a table of MAC addresses for the device connected to each port.  This allows it to forward the correct packet appropriately.

Comment: @JD87 If the IP address is on the local subnet, the router does not come into play. ARP (again, broadcast, like DHCP is) is used to translate it into a MAC address, which it is then sent to. If the IP address is on a *different* subnet, it's sent via the gateway (router), which may or may not apply NAT - consumer routers typically do apply NAT.

Comment: @Bob Ah right, I get you! So even in my home network without the additional switch, my router is only acting as a router when communicating with a different network. When communicating between attached devices it is just acting as a switch using MAC addresses. Cheers for all help, that's cleared a couple of things up for me!

Comment: @JD87 :) Your typical consumer "router" is actually a router and a switch and sometimes a wireless access point combined in one package - but they actually serve distinct roles and are usually distinct devices in enterprise equipment.

Comment: @Bob This is a bit of a late reply but I've just thought of another question - If a router basically acts as a switch using MAC addressing, why is an internal private IP range needed?

Comment: @JD87 It's not, if you turn off DHCP on the router. The router component often can't be turned off, and that leaves you with setting a private IP to access the built-in webserver to configure it, but you generally shouldn't need a *range* unless you have DHCP enabled - but it all depends on how much the router lets you disable - consumer routers are sometimes not very configurable and will *only* act in its full router/switch/modem role.

Comment: @JD87 If you're talking about private IP on your network in general, that's because most devices/protocols work on layer 3 or higher, which normally means working on top of IP [de-facto layer-3 protocol] (normally, HTTP is on top of TCP which is on top of IP, which itself sits on top of on MAC). On the local network, this gets translated directly to a MAC address by your machine, otherwise it goes through NAT on your gateway for access to the outside network (WAN). It's all about abstraction (IP is more than just addressing, an IP packet is different from an ethernet frame).

Comment: Basically, TCP doesn't want to worry about dealing with managing the layer-2 ethernet frames as well, so it lets layer-3 (IP) worry about that - and just assumes everything is sent as a layer-3 packet, not caring about what's underneath. Likewise, it doesn't care if your physical layer is wireless or wired or copper or fibre, etc., another layer manages that and translates it to a common protocol.

Comment: @Bob Thanks for taking the time to type all of that out for me! It's starting to make more sense now, it seems the more I learn, the more questions I need answering!

Comment: @JD87 Feel free to ask in [chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/118/root-access) if you want!